# sql joins how to join multiple tables

Tags: sql, join

I have 3 tables: medicationorder, Ordercatalog and Person

```
medicationOrder (
    startdate, 
    enddate,
    catalogId,
    orderId,
    personId)    

ordercatalog (
    catalogId, 
    drugId,
    IsGeneric,
    Brand)

Person (firsstname,
    lastname, 
    dob,
    personId)
```

I want to retrieve all medication orders for the patient with last name "cat"... I tried this.. can you please tell me where I'm going wrong.. Thanks..

```
select *
from ordercatalog as o, person as p, medicationorder as m

join ordercatalog on o.CatalogId= m.CatalogId, 

where (p.PersonId= m.PersonId and p.LastName= "Cat");
```

Comment: you can't mix notations Join and , separated froms the engine can't handle.  Pick one notation.

Comment: Hello - it would help if you stated that platform you're running on, MSAccess, MySql etc , the SQL syntax will change a little between them.  You're pretty close, you can do your joins in the Where clause (like you did with p.personid and m.personid) or you can explicitly call out your joins (Inner join ordercatalog on medicationorder.catalogid = ordercatalog.catalogid) but not both.  Usually best to explicitly call out your joins, doing it in the where clause is 'old hat'.  You're getting there though!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM mo JOIN person p ON mo.personId=p.personId JOIN ordercatelog o ON mo.catelogId=o.catelogId WHERE p.lastname='cat';`

Comment: @deanosaur, really trying not to be snooty here as I've posted an answer, but rather than posting an answer in comments, you ought to upvote an answer that you like or post your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've combined two different SQL standards.

The older standard called SQL89:

```
select 
  *
from 
  ordercatalog as o, 
  person as p,
  medicationorder as m
where
  o.CatalogId= m.CatalogId
  and p.PersonId= m.PersonId 
  and p.LastName= "Cat"
```

Notice that all the joins are handled in your `where` clause.

Conversely, you can do it based on the [SQL92](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92) standard that puts your joins in the `from` clause:

```
select
    *
from
    ordercatalog o
    inner join medicationorder m on o.CatalogId = m.CatalogId
    inner join person p on m.PersonId = p.PersonId and p.LastName = "Cat"
```

You should find that every platform out these days supports the SQL92 standard.  But most will support both.

Answer (score 1):

```
            SELECT * FROM 
            ORDERCATALOG O INNER JOIN MEDICATIONORDER M
            ON O.CATALOGID=M.CATALOGID
            INNER JOIN PERSON P
            ON P.PERSONID=M.PERSONID 
            AND P.LASTNAME='CAT';
```

Comment: I'm handing out upvote love on this answer in hopes that karma comes back to me.  Lots of right answers here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
 select * from medicationorder m 
inner join person p on p.PersonId = m.PersonId
inner join ordercatalog o on m.CatalogId=o.CatalogId where p.LastName = 'Cat';
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Great answer, what a difference 6 seconds make. :)  Not a lot of upvote love on this question, so here's one for you.